# How to automate button clicks based on colors in AHK?

Tags: python, automation, autohotkey

Is it possible to automate pressing a button when a color meets another color(check image for referance) in autohotkey or using python?

[The image for what the script is for (Press E when orange goes over white)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj1MO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding AHK
To really activate an element using AHK you have to use the COM wrapper. Otherwise you have to resort to dirty tricks like finding your button by sending tabs, guessing its coordinates, using OCR etc.

Looking at your picture I assume it's from a game. That most likely excludes COM wrapper. If your button pops and goes that will exclude coodrinates and hotkeys. I didn't get the "color meets another color" part, but I suppose, optical recognition is your best bet.

Try your luck with this library, unless the game uses special rendering layers.
https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=18719